# I can't get <input> value populated with full name, only shows first name

Tags: javascript, html

I've the following code and i want it to display "John Doe" or "Jane Doe", but instead i only get "John" or "Jane".

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head><title></title></head>
<body>

<select id='name'>
<option value='' selected></option>
<option value='John Doe'>John Doe</option>
<option value='Jane Doe'>Jane Doe</option>
</select><br>
<br><input type='button' value='submit' onclick='display()'>

<p id="result"></p>

<script>
function display() {
document.getElementById("result").innerHTML = "<input type='text' value="+document.getElementById("name").value+">"
}
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

It's important to pass the full name to the Input Value.
If I use instead:

```
document.getElementById("result").innerHTML=document.getElementById("name").value
```

it works but it's not the solution that I pretend.

Comment: For content with spaces, you'll need some quotes around the `value`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should pass the value in the quotes. Without quotes it takes `value=John` and `Doe` as a different attribute.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head><title></title></head>
<body>

<select id='name'>
<option value='' selected></option>
<option value='John Doe'>John Doe</option>
<option value='Jane Doe'>Jane Doe</option>
</select><br>
<br><input type='button' value='submit' onclick='display()'>

<p id="result"></p>

<script>
function display() {
document.getElementById("result").innerHTML = "<input type='text' value='"+document.getElementById("name").value+"'>"
}
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

You are missing quotes:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head><title></title></head>
<body>

<select id='name'>
<option value='' selected></option>
<option value='John Doe'>John Doe</option>
<option value='Jane Doe'>Jane Doe</option>
</select><br>
<br><input type='button' value='submit' onclick='display()'>

<p id="result"></p>

<script>
function display() {
document.getElementById("result").innerHTML = "<input type='text' value=\""+document.getElementById("name").value+"\">"
}
</script>

</body>
</html>
```